# Text banner over image not aligned properly

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm relatively new to CSS and I'm stuck with trying to make a banner go over an image.
I'm not sure how to make the text sit in the middle rather than being aligned to the top, and also if you notice, the banner does not go completely to the end on the right hand side, leaving a small gap.

[image]

```css
.article-box4 {
    background-image: url("Thumbnails/Anatomy_of_a_Sunset-2.jpg");
        background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.award-ribbon {
    height: 35px;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #49c2d7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    right: -6px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.award-ribbon:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 37px;
    border-left-width: 53px;
    border-right-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -49px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 141%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: #49c2d7;
    top: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
  <div class= "article-box-wrap">
      <div class = "award-ribbon"> Award Winner</div>
      <div class = "article-box4"></div> 
      <div class = "article-title-container">
          <img class= "newspaper-logo" src="logos/paper.jpg"/>
      <p class = "article-title">Insert title of article here</p> </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Many thanks if you can point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox will work in this case,  see snippet.

```css
.article-box4 {
    background-image: url("Thumbnails/Anatomy_of_a_Sunset-2.jpg");
        background-repeat: none;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}

.award-ribbon {
    height: 35px;
    display: flex;
    width: 180px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #49c2d7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    right: -6px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(35deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(35deg);
    transform: rotate(35deg);
}

.award-ribbon:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-width: 37px;
    border-left-width: 53px;
    border-right-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -49px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 141%;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-color: #49c2d7;
    top: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/">
  <div class= "article-box-wrap">
      <div class = "award-ribbon"> Award Winner</div>
      <div class = "article-box4"></div> 
      <div class = "article-title-container">
          <img class= "newspaper-logo" src="logos/paper.jpg"/>
      <p class = "article-title">Insert title of article here</p> </div>
  </div>
</a>
```